# Auto complete on search bar is very slow

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

**When I want to write a text on the search button, it comes too late. I don't know what exactly is the reason for this, but I think it is due to the onChanged part. Can you help me?**

> **My code**

```
    import 'package:easy_debounce/easy_debounce.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_form_builder/flutter_form_builder.dart';
    import 'package:get/get.dart';
    import 'package:novadan_admin/global/utilities/consts_design.dart';
    import 'package:novadan_admin/global/utilities/consts_tools.dart';
    import 'package:novadan_admin/modules/orders/orders_main/controllers/orders_main_controller.dart';

class OrdersMainDataTableHeaderSearchBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final OrdersMainController orderMainController = Get.find();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        width: 200,
        height: 40,
        child: FormBuilderTextField(
          name: 'search',
          initialValue: "",
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: "searchlabel".tr,
              hintText: "searchhint".tr,
              suffixIcon: searchButtonSuffixDecoration()),
          onChanged: (newValue) {
            orderMainController.formKey.value.currentState?.fields['search']?.didChange(newValue);
            orderMainController.update();
          },
          validator: FormBuilderValidators.compose([]),
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
        ));
  }
}
```

1. **design**

[image: design]

2. **Console**
   [image: Console]

Answer (score 0):

try to remove C:\Users<your_name>\AppData\Local.dartServer
(this is the cache of Analysis Server,it might worth to reset it)
Then restart the server.

this solved my issue in windows check [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/3255)